# Parsec: line continuation trouble

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am having trouble figuring this out.

So if a string is followed by one or many newline chars without one or many spaces after it - it is an end of line and I return the line. If a string is followed by one or many newline chars  and then one or many spaces after that - it is a line continuation and I keep going till I encounter newlines without spaces. Then return it.

This just totally locked my brain. Please help.

**UPDATE**

In case there is a confusion about my explanation above, I give an example

```
From: John Doe <j.doe@gmail.com>
To: dude@cooldomain.biz
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary=047d7b2e4e3cdc627304eb094bfe
```

Given the above text I should be able to parse 3 lines for further processing like so

```
["From: John Doe <j.doe@gmail.com>", "To: dude@cooldomain.biz", "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7b2e4e3cdc627304eb094bfe"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this pseudocode, perhaps (assuming you want to keep all the whitespace):

```
continuedLine = go "" where
    go s = do
        s'      <- many (noneOf "\n")
        empties <- many (char '\n')
        let soFar = s ++ s' ++ empties
        (char ' ' >> go (soFar ++ " ")) <|> return soFar
```

Apply your favorite transformation to eliminate the deeply-nested left-associated `++`s.

**EDIT**: Hm, it just occurred to me that there's a subtlety I may have overlooked. In case this is not a continuation, are you hoping to leave the newlines "unparsed", so to speak? If so, you can use `try` to do something like this:

```
continuedLine = go "" where
    continuationHerald = do
        empties <- many (char '\n')
        char ' '
        return (empties ++ " ")

    go s = do
        s'   <- many (noneOf "\n")
        cont <- try (Just <$> continuationHerald) <|> return Nothing
        case cont of
            Nothing -> return (s ++ s')
            Just empties -> go (s ++ s' ++ empties)
```

Note that we go to some length to avoid putting the recursive call to `go` inside the `try`. This is an efficiency concern: doing so would cause the parser to refuse to give up on the alternate `return Nothing` branch, and prevent garbage collection of the beginning of the string being parsed.

Comment: It freakin works! How did you do it? Well, it was a rhetorical   question ... Looking at the complexity of it I probably would never figured it out. I was hoping I missed something simple. Now I need to go through your snippet and understand it. By looking at the output, I realized that I need to strip the newline and extra spaces from a continued line as well. Your first example is similar to what I was trying to do but I would test for a space after the newline and then recurse if true. Did not work though. So why didn't  you like your first example? It works as expected too..

Comment: @r.sendecky The difference between the first snippet and the second is that the first snippet consumes the newlines of non-continuations, but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest splitting your parser into multiple passes, so the code for parsing expressions isn't cluttered with whitespace handling.  Example:

- `lex :: String -> [Token]`

  Handle whitespace and split input into tokens.
- `parse :: Parsec [Token] Expr`

  Convert a stream of tokens to an expression tree.

Here's a pretty straightforward way to join continued lines:

```
-- | For each line with whitespace in front of it,
-- remove it and append it to the preceding line.
joinContinuedLines :: [String] -> [String]
joinContinuedLines [] = []
joinContinuedLines (x0:xs0) = go x0 xs0
  where
    go joinedLine (x : xs)
      | startsWithSpace x = go (joinedLine ++ x) xs
      | otherwise         = joinedLine : go x xs
    go joinedLine [] = [joinedLine]

    startsWithSpace (x:_) = isSpace x
    startsWithSpace ""    = False
```